# Why i am no getting able to write text into a file

Tags: java

I have written a simple code to write text into file but i am not able to figure out why text is not written to file. I have written a class with method which will take text file as input and create the text file if it is not exist

here is the code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

public class OutputFile {

    public static BufferedWriter fbw = null;

    public BufferedWriter createFile(String text)
    {
        try{
            File file =new File(text);
            if(!file.exists()){
                file.createNewFile();
            }
            FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(text,true);
            fbw =new BufferedWriter(writer);
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        return fbw;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
    {
        String resultFilePath = "C:/Users/Desktop/stringcompare/output.txt";
        OutputFile file = new OutputFile();
        fbw = file.createFile(resultFilePath);
        fbw.write("hello");
        fbw.newLine();
        fbw.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any exception?

Comment: try adding `fbw.flush()` before `fbw.close()`

Comment: its' working fine for me.

Comment: Does `C:/Users/Desktop/stringcompare` exist?

Comment: Braj, i am not getting any exception, nothing is written to my text file.

Comment: Axel, from my code , if it is not exist then it will create the file

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
try(BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("FILE_PATH_HERE"))){

    br.write("STUFF_TO_WRITE_HERE");

} catch(IOException e){

}
```

With this [try-with-resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) statement, all of the closing file effort is done automatically.

This will only work for Java 7 or higher.

Comment: It's worth mentioning this will only work in java 7 or higher.

Comment: It was a feature brought out in Java 7, so it's only compatible for that and future versions.

Answer (score 0):

You have to flush your output. This can be done directly by calling `writer.flush()`.

Comment: doesn't `close()` flush the data in the file?

Comment: It should, but I am used to flushing before closing, because I have experienced this very issue several times.